# what is the best way to write unit tests for a c++ lib from c#?

Tags: c#, c++, unit-testing

Assume that there are many managed modules that call into unmanaged modules. The test framework tests the managed module. I would like to test the independent c++ modules in the lib but make it run as part of the current test framework. Currently, I am thinking of using a c++ unit test framework and using pinvoke to call the unit test main method from the c# test framework. The c++ will output its results to the console and finally return success or failure to the managed test framework. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would be tempted to write a C++/CLI shim so you can invoke your unit tests directly from the current .NET test framework rather than bring s second one into the picture and try to mix and match the results.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Timo's suggestion that you would be better off using only a single test framework.  But instead of a C++/CLI shim, which requires introducing some new technology and can raise difficult marshaling issues, my choice would be to find a way to invoke the tests directly via p/Invoke.  So I would write the shim code in C++ using either (or both) of two approaches:

- Where possible, write all the test logic in C#, so that the shim functions just lightly wrap your existing C++ logic, and the C# code invokes them just as the C++ code would.  (This is particularly easy if you factor your C++ functions into a DLL that can be used equally by your main application and your tests.  However that may not make sense if your interface is heavily class-oriented rather than being in a `WINAPI` style.  Even then however,  it's sometimes easy enough to write `WINAPI` shims that wrap a class interface, passing `this` around as an `LPVOID`.)  Anyway, the point is to write as little new C++ as possible.
- For code where the bulk of the test logic only makes sense to write in C++, a single `WINAPI` function per test that executes the test steps and returns a result (for example, returns true/false and populates an error string, or possibly throws an exception).